# How to pass data to an extended twig template

Tags: php, symfony, templates

I've a twig template named (header.html.twig) that i call in every template:`{% include "Bundle:Tempalte:header.html.twig" %}`. I want to passe some data to this template without using the `render` method of symfony. Here's the structure of the template calling.

**The controller :**

```
$this->render('index.html.twg',array());
```

**The Index twig template index.html.twg  :**

```
{% include "Bundle:Tempalte:header.html.twig" %}`
    {% block code %}
       //some html code
    {% endblock %}
```

So there's any solutions please.

Comment: erm, add a global variable to your twig environment? you can do this in the [config.yml file](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html), but you might want to consider creating an extension (it's at the bottom of the same page I linked to)

Comment: What about using a service? You could call it from your `header.html.twig` and let the service calculate anything you need.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Thanks, I think that shoud help me to do what i want.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% include "Bundle:Template:header.html.twig" with {'foo': 'bar'} %}
```

Read the documentation : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

Comment: I don't wanna a static value. And it's not what i want :). Thanks

Comment: @KubiRoazhon, sure, you can pass the data from the controller to the index template that will be pass the data to the header template with the sintax highlighted in this answer

Comment: but he doesn't want to use the render method :) so yeah a service should do the thing